# How to send user's icon Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

As the headline says, I would be really grateful if someone explained to me how to send user's avatar picture as a message. So it would be something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `avatar_url` attribute of a `member` object and put it in an `Embed` as an image url.
Example:

```py
@bot.command()
async def avatar(ctx):
    emb = discord.Embed()
    emb.set_image(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```